# Npm and git need to publish "node_modules" (dependencies)?

Tags: git, npm, push, publish

I have a question about the good practice to publish on npm and git.

I have some package that require (with dependencies) a module (ex: bootstrap).

When I create my package.json with the method of "npm install bootstrap" it's creating a nodes_modules with bootstrap in my directory, but if I just put "dependencies bootstrap" inside the package.json without do a "npm install bootstrap" it's not create the "nodes_modules".

In the two case, after I publish my package (with npm publish), when I install the package on my prod application the "dependencies" call "bootstrap" normaly (with or without my "nodes_modules" where I had create the package).
So my first question is that I don't understand if it is better to publish my package with "nodes_modules" or without ? (because in both of case in practice it's working..)

Also if I choose to publish my package with "nodes_modules", after I want to commit my package and push it with git, but it's create the "nodes_modules" and "package-lock.json" on my github repositories.
So my second question is : It's good practice to keep "nodes_modules" and "package-lock.json" on github ? or it's better to ignore them ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include `node_modules` in your repo or publish it.

You should include `package.json` in your repo and publish it; I don't see how you could avoid that, as this is the basic description of the package you're distributing.

According to the documentation, you should check in the package-lock file to source control, but it is not published.  I find this usage bizarre, but it appears to be the intended usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I will not include "nodes_modules" to my repo or publish it to npm (it's seem better like that). Also I will keep "package-lock" file for publish and commit to my repo (for "package.json" of course I will push it, I have poorly formulated my question sorry for that).